# Why won't my BroadcastReceiver call other methods?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver that can successfully catch a broadcast, but if I try to call another method from it, it won't always work.  Here's my setup:

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (working == true) {
            //toast to make sure we got here
            doWork();
        }
    }
}
```

The toast within the if gets called, but doWork doesn't execute.  Has anyone dealt with a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Broadcast receiver doesn't have the same context and life cycle as your application, you can't do a lot of normal stuff in it.  All your supposed to do is handle the event and return as quick as possible.  In other words, start a service, or notify the user.

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.

In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll mess with this tonight.

Comment: Do you have a simple example for how to start the Service from the BroadcastReceiver?  I'm still trying to get down how it works.

Comment: I got it going.  Service is what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's not staying awake long enough. Are you using a WakeLock to keep Android from going back to sleep?

So, firstly you'll need to add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and then in your receiver //pseudo code except for the parts that matter...

```
 public WakeLock wl;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(c,i){
       wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, TAG);//this matters
       wl.getWakeLock().acquire(); //as does this


       //do whatever but DON'T do it here... call a Service like this...
       Intent i = new Intent(context, MyExcellentService.class);

        try {
    PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,i, 0).send();
         }catch(Exception e){}

       //hold on to wl in some way and release it in the service, not here,
       wl.getWakeLock().release();


    }
```

If you're going to use a service you'll need to register it in your manifest like so...

```
<service android:name="MyExcellentService" />
```

And I would extend the Application and hold on to the WakeLock there, so that you don't have to pass it around in more convoluted ways. You can just reach up into the Application and talk straight to it!

You'll want to look up the differences in the *kinds of wakeups PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK will not keep the screen awake, for example, just the background processing.

Let me know if this works, I'm cutting and pasting from various places, so, I may be overlooking something.

Comment: I didn't even know that was an issue.  I haven't looked at WakeLock before.  Is it simple to implement?

Comment: Thanks, dude.  I'm going insane over here.

Comment: Gimme a sec to put this in, and I'll let you know.

Comment: I don't think you need the getWakeLock() attached to wl, since wl already is the WakeLock.  Eclipse isn't recognizing the TAG constant at the moment, so I have to figure out how to include that.  Also, you gotta define pm, which is a PowerManager.  I found another example that shows how to do that.  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(                        Context.POWER_SERVICE);

Comment: I think it works.  I have more experimenting to do, but it's definitely better than it was.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: The TAG is just a local string, it can be set to anything.  And the second poster is right, you don't want to be *doing anything in the broadcast receiver other than delegating tasks to a Service.

Comment: Looks like I need to look into Services, then.

Comment: I'm reading about them right now.  I'm getting a general sense about it, but is there a simple example for how to kick off a service from the BroadcastReceiver somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure why I lost the correct answer checkmark... I told you to use a service and added code to show you how to do it... also, your problem was, in fact, the WakeLock absence (though in addition to that it's obviously correct to use the service).  You *could run the whole thing in your receiver if you wanted to... it's just not correct to do so.  And by the way, you still have to use a WakeLock... otherwise your Service will get shut down, unless it's doing something super speedy (within about 10 seconds).