# Stop a service in a broadcast receiver and update an entry in a SQLite DB

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-service

i want to check if we are connected to the Internet in my application. I am using a broadcastReceiver. If the connection is lost i want to change an entry in my DB SQLite and stop a service which does htpp requests in another thread every minute.
Log.i doesn't display anything, when i try to update my DB or stop the service , my application crashes and i have no error message in logcat and no exception.

```
public class InternetConnection extends BroadcastReceiver {

private AccountBDD accountBdd;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null) {
        State networkState = networkInfo.getState();
        if (networkState.compareTo(State.CONNECTED) == 0)
            Log.i("INTERNET CONNEC", "connection retrieved");
        Toast.makeText(context, "RETRIEVED CONNECTION ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECTION LOST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("INTERNET CONNEC", "loss of connection");

    // context.stopService(new Intent(context, PeriodicSync.class));
    // accountBdd.updateSyncUtility(syncUtility);
    // Log.i(" Value ", " offlineWork = "
    // + accountBdd.getSyncUtility().getOfflineWork());
}
}
```

the manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:label="@string/app_banner" 
    android:name="SQLiteApplication">

    <service android:name="PeriodicSync" /> 

    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.android.InternetConnection">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>


</application>
```

has anybody an idea ? Thx

Comment: working in eclipse? if so, can u debug and check that you do get into the receiver at all?

Comment: i have two breakpoints in the receiver and i don't reach them, but when i press F8 to stop the connection my toast messages are diplayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045836/why-wont-my-broadcastreceiver-call-other-methods . It seems to be the reason why it doesn't display my Log.i messages.